# Weekly date change for href url

Tags: javascript

I publish a weekly newsletter, the file path is the same and the file name is similar apart from the date. I publish the newsletter every week (7 days). So every 7 days I have to change the link and add 7 days to the date. The date needs to be referenced so I cant just add the file as "newsletter" it has to be ".../newsletter-DDMMYY.pdf"

```
<a href="/newsletter-040314">Weekly Newsletter</a>
```

How do I use javascript to change the date part of the url above scheduled for every 7 days?

Comment: What is the hard part, changing the `href`, finding every 7th day or formatting a date? All? Also sounds like a task for server-side rather than JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript solution

```
<body>
    <a id="newsletter">Weekly Newsletter</a>

    <script>
        function getNewsletterDate () {
            var DAY_OF_NEWSLETTER = 6 // 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday, 4 for Thursday, 5 for Friday, 6 for Saturday
            var day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            var date = new Date();
            var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
            date = new Date(date.getTime() - (dayOfWeek - DAY_OF_NEWSLETTER) * day);
            if (date > new Date()) date = new Date(date - 7 * day)
            return date;
        }

        function updateNewsletterLink() {
            var date = getNewsletterDate();
            var link = document.getElementById('newsletter');
            var href = '/newsletter-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + (''+date.getYear()).slice(-2);
            link.href = href;
        }

        updateNewsletterLink();
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) is a great library for this kind of thing:

Adding 7 days to a date:

```
moment("040314", "DDMMYY").add('d',7).format("DDMMYY")
```

Or a week:

```
moment("040314", "DDMMYY").add('w',1).format("DDMMYY")
```

Same output:

```
"110314"
```